# get current url outside of router-outlet

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I want to get current url. For that I'm doing

```
constructor(public router: Router) { ... }
ngOnInit() { console.log(this.router.url); }
```

and it works ok. But now I want to move it to layout component which is parent of every component. And I have `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` inside of `layoutcomponent`.

When I log this code inside of layout component it logs: `/`

what can I do?

Comment: `/` is root of app in angular better you can go with javascript method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a Router event and subscribe to it

```
constructor(router: Router) {
    this.router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => {
        console.log(event.url); // This will give you the required url
    });
}
```

Comment: Why is this answer marked as correct? Cause it is not.

Comment: @izulito works for me. 1 thing to add is `if ( event instanceof NavigationEnd )`

Answer (score 1):

The routers approach already mentioned is an effective one to get the relative url in your app. For instance, if you have a local site: http://localhost:3000/my/fine/site

Taking the approach already mentioned in the first answer of subscribing to the router events and logging the updated value is useful for getting the Relative path in your app:

```
constructor(router: Router) {
this.router.events.subscribe((e: Event) => {
            console.log("Relative URL is: ", event.url);
    });
}
```

> Relative URL is: /my/fine/site

If you want to get the FULL url, you can always use vanilla JS in your angular app like:

```
console.log("FULL URL is: ", window.location.href);
```

> FULL URL is: http://localhost:3000/my/fine/site

The drawback of that is that it's not a subscribed value, so it doesn't get updated on view changes (changes that don't reload the window)... unless you combine the event listener with the vanilla JS url, giving you easy access to the current value of either:

```
constructor(router: Router) {
this.router.events.subscribe((e: Event) => {
            console.log("Relative URL is: ", event.url);
            console.log("Updated FULL URL is: ", window.location.href);
    });
}
```

> Relative URL is: /my/fine/site/pagechange
>
> Updated FULL URL is: http://localhost:3000/my/fine/site/pagechange

This came in handy when I wanted the current full url for a social sharing link, but was outside of the router-outlet. There is some talk that Angular may address the lack of convenience in getting url & params outside of a router outlet (currently have to do a little bit of walking the tree - which can be brittle). https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11023

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `event.url` directly on events subscribe function angular throws error

> Property 'url' does not exist on type 'Event'
>
> Property 'url' does not exist on type 'RouteConfigLoadStart'.

So better you've to use the following to avoid such error: First you have to import `Event, Router` from `@angular/router`

```js
import { Router, Event } from "@angular/router"; // Include in the top of your component
```

Then inject `Router` in your constructor to access the current state

```js
constructor(private router: Router){}
```

Finally, You've to check `event` is the instance of `NavigationEnd`, add your this code inside `ngOnInit()` function

```js
this.subscription = this.router.events.subscribe((event:Event) => {
    if(event instanceof NavigationEnd ){
        console.log(event.url);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import { Router, NavigationEnd  } from '@angular/router'; 
constructor( private router: Router) {} 
ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.subscribe(e => {
     if (e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
       console.log(e.url);
      }
    });
}
```